# getting a No such file or directory error with Kubernetes cronjob and dockerfile

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a script that I want to run using a dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM debian:unstable-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat-traditional httpie postgresql-client

COPY go.sh /tmp/go.sh

WORKDIR /tmp
CMD ["bash", "-c", "/tmp/go.sh"]
```

It works fine on local, but I need to deploy it as a kubernetes cronjob, I have a config file with something like this:

```
script:
- docker build -t {github_enterprise_url/org/repo} .
```

And the build output seems ok:

```
...
Step 3/7 : COPY go.sh /tmp/go.sh
 ---> ab8d5227f65e
...
Successfully built e79162d90def
```

And for the cronjob yaml, among other things, I have something like this:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - image: >-
        ${ trigger.artifacts.?[type == 'docker'].?[name matches
        'org/repo'].![reference][0] }
```

the deploy then succeded but with this message:

```
Cannot determine if job needs to be started: Too many missed start time (> 100). Set or decrease .spec.startingDeadlineSeconds or check clock skew.
```

So I tried to run it manually like this:

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/name name-manual-123
```

And when looking at the logs for the pod created, I get this:

```
kubectl logs name-manual-123-ab1cd
bash: line 1: /tmp/go.sh: No such file or directory
```

any clue?

Comment: Is something like a tmpfs getting mounted on `/tmp`, hiding your script?  Does moving the script to `/usr/local/bin` help?

Comment: I don't know how to check the tmpfs thing but that's probably the issue. It's working now by moving the script to `/usr/local/bin`. Post it as an answer and I will accept it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/tmp` directory is generally intended for temporary file storage.  It's common to mount a RAM disk (`tmpfs`) there, and it's possible the Kubernetes setup does this without you noticing it.

You can address this by storing your script in a location that's on the default `PATH`, like `/usr/local/bin`:

```sh
# /usr/local/bin, not /tmp
COPY go.sh /usr/local/bin

CMD ["go.sh"]
# will work when the script is executable; on $PATH (in /usr/local/bin);
# and has a correct shebang line
# #!/bin/sh
```